# Change permanently a link using cookies or local storage

Tags: html

I need to save the choices made in a dropdown list with cookies or localstorage.
Then with the choice I have to change the links contained in an `<href>`

If anyone would like to help me I thank him in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://defaulturl.com" id="demo">Link</a>
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="default" selected="false">Keep default</option>
  <option value="alternative">Use alternative</option>
</select>
<button onclick="setcookie()">Set preference</button>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var cookiecount = document.cookie.split("; ");
  var foundcookie = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < cookiecount.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookiecount[i].split("=");
    if (cookie[0] == "preference") {
      foundcookie = cookie[1]
    }
  }
  if (foundcookie == false) {
    document.cookie = "preference=default; ";
    var a = document.getElementById("demo");
    a.href = "https://defaulturl.com";
  } else if (foundcookie == "alternative") {
    var a = document.getElementById("demo");
    a.href = "https://alternativeurl.com";
  } else {
    var a = document.getElementById("demo");
    a.href = "https://defaulturl.com";
  }
}

function setcookie() {
  var userpreference = document.getElementById("options").value;
  document.cookie = "preference=" + userpreference.toString() + "; ";
  if (userpreference == "default") {
    var a = document.getElementById("demo");
    a.href = "https://defaulturl.com";
  } else {
    var a = document.getElementById("demo");
    a.href = "https://alternativeurl.com";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It will check if the cookie is stored, and if not, set it to the default. Then it will check the cookie value, and change the link accordingly. There's also a function to reset the cookie with that dropdown.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: Could the problem be that I try it in localhost?

Comment: No that was my mistake. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Nope :(   it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, I'm very grateful